# notepad++ regex does not replace but deletes

Tags: notepad++, regex

I can't make a simple replacement with notepad++ regex.
I need to put newline after the line that starts with a number.

```
5. Rock
Capitolo 1 – Il camion
```

This regex deletes the first line, instead of putting a new line after it.

```
Find what: ^(\d.*)$

Replace with: \1\n
```

Comment: works fine on notepad v7.8.6, no need for newline. I use `\1 - x` w/o new line as replace, and `-x` was added.

Comment: @Archemar I have notepad++ with the same version. If I use \1 - x I get line replaced with  - x. So it does not work for me.

Comment: If `\1` is not working, then try replacing it with`$1`. So your replace with will be `$1\n`

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio. Thanks! $1 works for me!

Comment: @LetzerWille Should I answer the question?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio. Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot explain why `\1` is not working on your side. But in the meantime, you can replace `\1` with `$1` making your Find what to be `\$1\n`.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution without capture groups that slow down the process:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\d.*$\K`
- Replace with: `\n` or `\r` or `\r\n` depending on platform
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  \d            # a digit
  .*            # 0 or more any character but newline
$               # end of line
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I never knew about \K.